# Java 8 Date how to check if time is older then X seconds?

Tags: java, date, java-8, java-time

Using the new Java 8 DateTime API (java.time) how can we check if the "last" capture time is older then a configured set of seconds?

Example...

Last captured time: 13:00:00 
Current time time: 13:00:31

```
if (last captured time is older then 30 seconds) then
    do something
```

Comment: What did you find in the [`java.time` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) when you did your research?

Comment: Yes I know looking at it now. I'm thinking I can use duration and calculate from that?

Comment: @user432024 I am thinking you should at least try.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.between(
    myEarlierInstant ;       // Some earlier `Instant`. 
    Instant.now() ;          // Capture the current moment in UTC. 
)
.compareTo(                  // Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.
    Duration.ofMinutes( 5 )  // A span of time unattached to the timeline. 
)
> 0
```

## Details

The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution in nanoseconds.

```
Instant then = … ;
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

A [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) represents a span of time in terms of seconds and [nanoseconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Duration d = Duration.between( then , now );
```

Extract the number of whole seconds.

```
long secondsElapsed = d.getSeconds() ;
```

Compare to your limit. Use [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum to convert rather than hard-coding a “magic” number. For example, converting five minutes to a number of seconds.

```
long limit = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds( 5 );
```

Compare.

```
if( secondsElapsed > limit ) { … }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also the `getSeconds()` method:

```
Instant start = Instant.now()
// Do something
Instant end = Instant.now()

if (Duration.between(start, end).getSeconds() > 30) {
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Duration it is...

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(xx));
System.out.println(duration.getSeconds());
```

Comment: The `Local…` classes purposely lose all time zone and offset-from-UTC information. So this is the wrong class to be using here. **This kind of code fails** when executing during a Daylight Saving Time (DST) cut-over or other such anomaly.